# About /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml

Tags: java, spring, tapestry

This is driving me nuts. And this has been probably asked before but....

I've started recently with Tapestry for a Hibernate-Spring-Tapestry project. I used a maven archetype for Hibernate/Tapestry and then added Spring integration but this is giving more problems than I thought.

Currently I'm stuck with this, after adding the right tapestry-spring integration dependency and after changing the filter in /WEB-INF/web.xml I can't get jetty to run. This is because it can't find /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml, mostly because I don't have that file in my project.

I just want to know what it should contain so I can move on to my next noob error.

EDIT: I've replaced the default Tapestry5 filter with

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>app</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.tapestry5.spring.TapestrySpringFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
```

Full web.xml -> http://pastebin.com/KgPTDrmC

Comment: What filter did you add?

Comment: post your web-inf.xml, applicationContext.xml and the logfile

Comment: I've posted my web.xml, I can't post my /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml because I don't have one, I'm asking about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TapestrySpringFilter` works by retrieving the `WebApplicationContext` created and initialized by Spring's `ContextLoaderListener` (which you should also have). The `applicationContext.xml` file is a Spring XML bean declaration file which the `ContextLoaderListener` can use to create that `WebApplicationContext`.

The beans that go in it depend on your application.